# Solving a Convex Resource Allocation Problem - Log of a Linear Term with Linear Equality Constraints

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, operations-research

I want to solve the following optimization problem

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n \log_{2}(1+a_i x_i)\\ \text{subject to} & \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n (c_i - x_i) a_i = b\\ & 0 \leq x_i \leq c_i\end{array}$$

where $a_i \geq a_2 \geq \dots \geq a_n$, $b \in \mathbb R^+$ and $c_1 = c_2 = \dots = c_n$ are given.

I tried to solve this problem using Lagrange multipliers

$$\mathcal{L}(x,\lambda,\mu,\nu)=\sum_{i=1}^n\log_{2}(1+a_ix_i) + \lambda \left( \sum_{i=1}^n(c_i-x_i)a_i - b \right) - \mu_i (x_i-c_i) + \nu_ix_i$$

We need to have $\frac{d\mathcal{L}}{dx_i}=0$; therefore

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i}{\ln(2)\times(1+a_ix_i)}-\lambda a_i-\mu_{i}+\nu_{i}=0$$

In particular, my problem always has

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} a_i c_i < b < \sum_{i=1}^n a_i c_i$$

How can I obtain the optimal values of $x_i$

Comment: One "trick" would be to discard the inequality constraints and add $$\gamma \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n \left( \log (x_i) + \log (c_i -x_i) \right)$$ to the objective function, where $\gamma > 0$. In other words, "hard" constraints are replaced by "soft" constraints.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Thank you for your response.Does this mean that  I need to solve the following optimization problem$ \gamma \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n \left( \log (x_i) + \log (c_i -x_i) \right) $constrained by  $\sum_{i}^{n}(c_i-x_i)a_i=b$. What abot $\gamma$? How can I deal with it?

Comment: No, you solve $$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n \log_{2}(1+a_i x_i) + \gamma \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n \left( \log (x_i) + \log (c_i -x_i) \right)\\ \text{subject to} & \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n (c_i - x_i) a_i = b\end{array}$$ As you vary parameter $\gamma > 0$, you weigh more the original objective or the soft constraints. The optimal solution should not be the same as the optimal solution of the original problem, but it should be much easier to find.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Thank you for the clarification. It seems the optimal values of $x_i$ can be obtained only numerically. I thought an analytical solution exists for this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your best approach is duality.  First, note that $\log_2$ and $\ln$ differ by a multiplicative constant $\ln(2)$. Thus, we can minimize with $\ln$ and obtain the same optimal value, and I will use $\ln$ instead of $\log_2$ in my derivations. Second, I will treat it as a minimization problem, and therefore write $-\ln$ instead of $\ln$.

Giving a Lagrange multiplier *only* to the equality constraint, you obtain the Lagrangian
$$
\begin{aligned}
L(x, \lambda) 
 &= -\sum_{i=1}^n \ln(1+a_i x_i) + \lambda \left[ \sum_{i=1}^n (c_i - x_i) a_i - b \right] \\
 &= \sum_{i=1}^n \left[-\ln(1+a_i x_i) - \lambda a_i x_i  \right] + \lambda \Bigl[\underbrace{-b + \sum_{i=1}^n a_i c_i}_{C} \Bigr]
\end{aligned}
$$
Since the Lagrangian and the constraints $0 \leq x_i \leq c_i$ are both separable in $x_i$, the dual objective is:
$$
q(\lambda) = \sum_{i=1}^n \min_{x_i} \biggl\{ -\ln(1+a_i x_i) - \lambda a_i x_i :~ 0 \leq x_i \leq c_i \biggr\} + \lambda C
$$
Note, that each of the elements in the sum above is a minimization of a convex function of the form $-\ln(1+ax) -bx$ over an interval, and it is quite easy to find a closed form solution (if you need help, please say so). From this solution you will also obtain a formula from recovering the optimal $x_i$ from the optimal $\lambda$.

Now, your dual problem is the one-dimensional optimization problem $\max_{\lambda} q(\lambda)$, which can be easily solved by a numerical method, such as the Golden Section search. After finding the optimal $\lambda^*$ you can recover $x^*$.

P.S. If you really want a really reliable method in terms of approximating the optimum in terms of the objective value, you can compute an approximate $x_i$ after every iteration of the the Golden Section search, and stop when the primal-dual gap is below some threshold.

## Update

Since there are many questions about computing $q(\lambda)$, here are the details. First, I will denote by $g_i(x_i, \lambda)$ the objective inside the minimum. That is, we solve
$$
\min_{x_i} \biggl\{g_i(x_i, \lambda) = -\ln(1+a_i x_i) - \lambda a_i x_i :~ 0 \leq x_i \leq c_i \biggr\} 
$$
The minimum is either a stationary point inside the interior of the interval $I = [0, c_i]$ or one of its endpoints.  First, note that if $\lambda \geq 0$ then $g_i$ is a decreasing function, and in this case there are no stationary points. Thus, for any stationary point we must have $\lambda < 0$.

To find a stationary point, we solve:
$$
\frac{d g_i}{d x_i} = -\frac{a_i}{1+a_i x_i} - \lambda a_i = 0.
$$
Since $a_i > 0$ we can divide both sides by $a_i$, and obtain the equation
$$
\frac{1}{1+a_i x_i} = -\lambda
$$
Since $\lambda \neq 0$, we take the inverse on both sides, multiply by $a_i$, and obtain
$$
1+a_i x_i = -\frac{1}{\lambda},
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
a_i x_i = -1-\frac{1}{\lambda},
$$
or
$$
x_i = -\frac{1+\lambda}{a_i \lambda}.
$$
Using the fact that $\lambda < 0$, we conclude that the point above is inside the interior of $I$ if and only if
$$
-1 < \lambda < -\frac{1}{1 + c_i a_i},
$$
in that case the expression for $x_i$ above is the minimizer, and the minimum is
$$
g_i\left(-\frac{1+\lambda}{a_i \lambda}, \lambda\right) = \ln(-\lambda) + \lambda + 1
$$
Otherwise, either the left endpoint $x_i=0$ or the right endpoint $x_i=c_i$ is the minimizer. To summarize,
$$
q_i(\lambda) = \min_{x_i} \biggl\{g_i(x_i, \lambda) :~ 0 \leq x_i \leq c_i \biggr\} = \begin{cases}
\ln(-\lambda) + \lambda + 1 & -1 < \lambda < -\frac{1}{1 + c_i a_i} \\
\min(0, -\ln(1+a_i c_i)-\lambda a_i c_i) & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
The dual objective is
$$
q(\lambda) = \sum_{i=1}^n q_i(\lambda) + \lambda C
$$
It is possible to simplify  the expressions above, but it is not required to do so in order to write code which evaluates $q(\lambda)$ in order to solve it numerically.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. Do you mean that I need to minimize the function $-\ln(1+ax)-bx$ to obtain  $x$ as a function of $a$ and $b$ then substitute this $x$  in the given Lagrangian $q(\lambda)$ and finally numerically solve $\text{max}_{\lambda}q(\lambda)$?

Comment: Exactly. You need to find a closed form expression for the minimizer $x$ and the resulting minimum as a function of $a,b$ and the endpoints of the interval. In that way you will have a formula for $q$ and you can use it to numerically maximize $q$.

Comment: I have computed the minimizer $x$ by taking the derivative of $\tilde{f}(x)=-\ln(1+ax)-bx$ then $\tilde{f}'(x)=0$ so we have  $x=\frac{-a-b}{ab}$. I'm confused about the value of $x$ because it always returns a negative number and the $\ln$-function is undefined  then

Comment: First, the sign of $-b$ is not always negative in our case  So it depends on whether $\lambda$ is positive or negative. Second and much more important, when minimizing over an interval you cannot just use the stationary point obtained from the "derivative=zero" equation. You need to take the endpoints of the interval into account too.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Do you mean that $\tilde{f}'(x) \neq 0$ and we need to test the endpoints to identify the minimizer $x$? I'm not sure how to this.

Comment: The candidates for the optimal solutions of $\min\{ f(x) : \alpha \leq x \leq \beta \}$ are: any point $x^*$ in the domain of $f$ satisfying $f'(x^*) = 0$, the point $x = \alpha$, the point $x = \beta$. In you case, you have either 3 or 2 candidates, depending on whether the point satisfying $f'(x) = 0$ is in the interval $[\alpha, \beta]$. The optimal solution is simply the candidate with the smallest value of $f$, and the minimum value is a piecewise function with two pieces, one for the case when the point satisfying $f'(x) = 0$ is inside the interval, and another piece for the opposite.

Comment: I think no point in the domain of $f$ satisfying $f'(x)=0$. However, I solved the original problem using CVX and find out that the optimal values of $x_i$ always returns $\log_2(1+a_2x_{1}^*)=\log_2(1+a_2x_{2}^*)=...=\log_2(1+a_nx_{n}^*)$  given that $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} a_i c_i < b < \sum_{i=1}^n a_i c_i$. I believe the solution is to be something like the water-filling.

Comment: I updated my answer to address your questions.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I have tested your solution against CVX and both return same answers. How can I prove the optimality of the given solution analytically?

Comment: The  strong duality theorem ensures that a pair feasible solutions, one for the primal and the other for the dual, are optimal if and only if the objectives of both problems at these points are equal. You can certify optimality by taking the results you obtained numerically and show that the difference between the primal and the dual objectives is less than some very small threshold, say $10^{-6}$.