# Budget Allocation Problem

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I have the following optimization problem
\begin{array}{ll} \mathrm{maximize} & \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^j k_i y_i,\\ \text{subject to} & \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^j \log_{2}(1+ k_iz_i)\geq C,\\ & 0 \leq y_i+z_i \leq q,~y_{i}\geq0,~ z_{i} \geq 0,\end{array}

where $k_i$, $q$ and $C$ are positive and real numbers. Both $y_i$ and $z_i$ are variables. I think we can get ride of the variable $z_{i}$ and update the problem as the following:
 \begin{array}{ll} \mathrm{maximize} & \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^j k_i y_i,\\ \text{subject to} & \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^j \log_{2}(1+ k_i(q-y_i))\geq C,\\ & 0 \leq y_i \leq q.\end{array}
Therefore, the Lagrangian function will be:
$$\mathcal{L}(y,\lambda,\mu,\nu)=\sum_{i=1}^{j}k_iy_i+\lambda\big(\sum_{i=1}^{j}\log_2(1+k_i(q-y_i))-C\big)+\mu_{i}(q-y_i)+\nu_{i}y_{i} $$
Assuming the problem is feasible, Using the KKT conditions and thinking about the complementary slackness: $\lambda>0$ which is true, but I think $\mu_{i}$ and $\nu_{i}$ are little bit tricky. In my opnion, if $y_i=q$, then  $\mu_i>0$, and $\nu_i=0$ and if $0<y_i<q$ , then $\mu_{i}=0$ and $\nu_{i}=0$ and finally if $y_i=0$, then $\mu_i>0$ and $\nu_i>0$. Therefor, I was not able to solve the problem based on the KKT system of equations(in case my analysis was correct). Any idea if there is a closed form solution for the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Your elimination of the $z$'s appears to be correct. Can be explained by performing a nested maximization - first w.r.t the $z$ variables, and then w.r.t the $y$ variables. I will leave the details of the proof to you.

Regarding a closed form solution, I do not believe one exists. However, you can easily write a simple algoithm for computing it, by solving a *one dimensional* problem. The trick is the similar as in here:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2711803/solving-a-convex-resource-allocation-problem/2712226#2712226

Comment: That's what I thought about the closed form solution. However, I spent a few days trying to convince my supervisor that the problem only has a numerical solution only. Thanks for the help

Comment: I hope that reduction to a one-variable problem is close enough to 'closed form' for your supervisor.

Comment: That's would be enough since it is the best approach we have now.

Comment: @AlexShtof I derived the following solution: (https://www.dropbox.com/s/7bs5uj5dto7mw1n/budget_solution.jpg?dl=0). I used the above solution and I have been asked to compare with the CVX solution of the original problem and unfortunately, CVX returns different values of $y_i$. Any idea what is wrong with the solution given here(see the image please)?

Comment: I can see three things that might go wrong. 

First, your relationship between $y_i$ and $\lambda$ (2nd equation) seems incorrect. Take $\lambda$ arbitrarily close to zero, and your $y_i$ is greater than $q$, which contradicts the constraint $y_i \leq q$.

Second, it might be that nothing is wrong, and your solution might be correct, since I do not see any apparent reason for the optimal solution to be unique. If you are getting the same objective value, you are good.

Third, CVX does not guarantee correct solutions in the presence of $\ln$. It uses an approximation.

Comment: But $\lambda$ lies inside the interval $[\ln2,\ln2(1+k_iq)]$ which guarantees $y_i \in [0,q]$ so any value of $\lambda$ outside the interval above returns no feasible $y_{i}$. Regarding CVX, I used $\textit{geo_mean}$ function instead of $\ln$ which gurantees a correct solution.

Comment: I do not see why is $\lambda$ guaranteed to lie there? Your dual function is well defined for values outside this interval too.

Comment: I meant we solve the dual function numerically where the $\lambda$ is lower bounded by $\ln2$ and upper bounded by $\ln2(1+k_iq)$ so we have a guarantee that $\lambda$ inside the interval given above